# How have phpMyAdmin (with a Alias) with a virtual host subdomain of a different documentRoot

Tags: centos, virtualhost, .htaccess, httpd

To increase security in my server I created an subdomain only for admin, like `admin.domain.tld` and usually i access phpmyadmin by going only at `admin.domain.tld/mysqladmin` as in config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName admin.domain.tld
    Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/

    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        AllowOverride All

    [...]

</VirtualHost>
```

now that I have have a subdomain i want to SSL secure it, for that i need to configure a virtual host or something like, (i use certbot aka let's encrypt), but as i have to configure a virtual host i decided to create a admin only html page in `admin.domain.tld` containing links to my admin pages like phpmyadmin, joomla admin page, etc...

config file:

```
    ServerName  admin.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.domain.tld
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/admin.domain.tld/error.log
    <Directory /var/www/admin.domain.tld>
            Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

but now when i go to `admin.domain.tld/mysqladmin` i get an error:

```
The requested URL /mysqladmin/ was not found on this server.
```

**So, how can i get it working like this:**

**admin.domain.tld is /var/www/admin.domain.tld

and

admin.domain.tld/mysqladmin is phpmyadmin**

EDIT:
i guess my problem is the alias is not working so when i go to admin.domain.tld it shows /var/www/admin.domain.tld/mysqladmin instead of /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Did you put the alias in?  You've only shown it here for the non-https virtual host.

Comment: @yoonix i didn't secured it with ssl yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a loop in the first config.  You send the alias to the same root directory, so when call the alias, will display the same root directory.  In that case, you will need a `mysqladmin` folder on `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/`.

Try to use `/var/www/admin.domain.tld` to root directory in both config files, so the alias `mysqladmin` will forward to the `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: my problem is the alias is not working so when i go to admin.domain.tld it shows /var/www/admin.domain.tld/mysqladmin instead of /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by putting the content of phpmyadmin virtual host together with the one of the admin.domain.tld. like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  admin.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/admin.domain.tld
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/admin.domain.tld/error.log
    <Directory /var/www/admin.domain.tld>
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        AllowOverride All

     [...]

</VirtualHost>
```